# Getting tox to reinstall console_scripts when package version changes

Tags: python, setuptools, tox

I'm using `tox` to test a module that has a script entry point defined in my `setuptools`-based `setup.py` script.

```py
entry_points={
    'console_scripts': [
        'myscript = mypackage:main',
    ],
}
```

`tox` is configured thus:

```
[testenv]
commands = pytest --cov=mypackage --cov-report=html --cov-append tests/
deps =
    pytest
    pytest-cov
usedevelop = True
```

As expected, the file `.tox/py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mypackage.egg-link` points back to my development directory, which obviously has the new version number.  The script installed at `.tox/py38/bin/myscript.py` includes the below reference to the old version number, and `tox` isn't updating it, so when I re-run `tox` after updating the version I end up getting a `VersionConflict` error.

```
==================================== ERRORS ====================================
_____________________ ERROR collecting tests/test_args.py ______________________
tests/test_args.py:6: in <module>
    import mypackage
.tox/py38/bin/mypackage.py:4: in <module>
    __import__('pkg_resources').require('mypackage==1.0.0b1')
.tox/py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py:900: in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
.tox/py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py:791: in resolve
    raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
E   pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (mypackage 1.0.0b2 (/Users/matt/devel/mypackage), Requirement.parse('mypackage==1.0.0b1'))
```

`tox` is installing the following two scripts in its `bin` directory which don't seem to get updated, and are triggering the above error:

```
% cat mypackage.py
#!/Users/matt/devel/mypackage/.tox/py38/bin/python
# EASY-INSTALL-DEV-SCRIPT: 'mypackage==1.0.0b1','mypackage.py'
__requires__ = 'mypackage==1.0.0b1'
__import__('pkg_resources').require('mypackage==1.0.0b1')
__file__ = '/Users/matt/devel/mypackage/mypackage.py'
with open(__file__) as f:
    exec(compile(f.read(), __file__, 'exec'))

% cat myscript
#!/Users/matt/devel/mypackage/.tox/py38/bin/python
# EASY-INSTALL-ENTRY-SCRIPT: 'mypackage','console_scripts','myscript'
__requires__ = 'mypackage'
import re
import sys
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw?|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(
        load_entry_point('mypackage', 'console_scripts', 'myscript')()
    )
```

Is there a way to convince `tox` to do a proper upgrade of the console script in its environment without manually wiping out all of the `.tox/` subdirectories every time I change the version number?

Comment: I don't really follow. Where does `mypackage.py` come from, how/why does it end up installed in `bin`?

Comment: Oops.  I made a mistake while trying to generalize this.  Fixed...

Comment: Still confusing from my point of view. I can't entirely figure out how the file `.tox/py38/bin/myscript.py` was generated. Could you add its content to the question?

Comment: Yes, but as far as I know, the console scripts generated by setuptools don't look like what the error trace shows, so I'm a bit confused. I could be mistaken though...

Comment: I've updated the question to include the scripts installed in `tox`'s `bin` directory

Comment: These files seem to have been generated by `easy_install`, which is unexpected. I do not believe _tox_ usually does that. Do you call `easy_install` somewhere? Also what's with `mypackage.py` and `myscript.py`, where do these come from, are they relevant? Question is still a bit confusing/inconsistent.

Comment: I'm not directly using `easy_install` anywhere.  I'm not sure what else I can clarify in the question ... this is what tox is doing, either by itself or indirectly through `setuptools` when it calls `setup.py`.  `myscript` is the script generated as a result of the `console_scripts` entrypoint... `mypackage.py` seems to be used by `myscript` as a layer of indirection before calling `mypackage:main`, but _why_ it does that is beyond my knowledge of the `setuptools` internals.

Comment: Do you by chance have a line in your `setup.py` (or `setup.cfg`) like the following: `scripts['mypackage.py']`?

Comment: did you find an answer to your question? After verification, the `easy_install` bit in the files found in `bin` is correct. But I do not believe there should be a `mypackage.py` file in this `bin` directory.